# Skip intermediate datetime values on X-axis in Pandas render

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a DataFrame, group and sum that by hour, which turns it into a Series. When I plot, that, the x-axis is completely garbled, unreadable.

Summarized in code:

```
bicycles = both_directions.query('type == "BICYCLE"')
display(bicycles.info())

timegroups = bicycles.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date_time', axis=0, freq="1H", sort=True)).count()['date']
display(timegroups)
display(type(timegroups.index))
timegroups.plot(kind="bar", stacked=True)
```

Which outputs:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 2025 entries, 0 to 3588
Data columns (total 9 columns):
 #   Column       Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------       --------------  -----         
 0   date_time    2025 non-null   datetime64[ns]
 1   speed        2025 non-null   int64         
 2   time         2025 non-null   object        
 3   date         2025 non-null   object        
 4   direction    2025 non-null   int64         
 5   length       2025 non-null   float64       
 6   length_norm  2025 non-null   int64         
 7   speed_norm   2025 non-null   int64         
 8   type         2025 non-null   string        
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1), int64(4), object(2), string(1)
memory usage: 158.2+ KB

None

date_time
2022-06-01 14:00:00     1
2022-06-01 15:00:00    11
2022-06-01 16:00:00     3
2022-06-01 17:00:00     8
2022-06-01 18:00:00     2
                       ..
2022-06-13 09:00:00     0
2022-06-13 10:00:00     5
2022-06-13 11:00:00    13
2022-06-13 12:00:00    12
2022-06-13 13:00:00    13
Freq: H, Name: date, Length: 288, dtype: int64

pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex

<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x7fcd133c3a90>
```

[image: Garbled X-Axis output from matplotlib]

What is the way to (smartly) skip values so that X-axis labels remain readable?

According to [Panda's documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/visualization.html#suppressing-tick-resolution-adjustment) it should already do this automatically, using default behaviour.

> Pandas includes automatically tick resolution adjustment for regular frequency time-series data.

But it is clear, it doesn't in this case. What am I doing wrong? Is there a setting or conversion I'm missing? Is it a type issue (series vs dataframe?)

Answer (score 1):

Given the following toy dataframe mimicking yours (one value per hour during one year), but with **duplicated** values (each hour in `date_time` column is repeated twice):

```py
import random

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "date_time": pd.to_datetime(
            pd.date_range(start="1/1/2021", end="12/31/2021", freq="H"), unit="H"
        )
    }
)
df["count"] = [int(random.random() * 100) for _ in range(df.shape[0])]
df = pd.concat([df, df]).reset_index(drop=True)  # Add duplicates
```

```py
df.info()
# Output
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 17474 entries, 0 to 17473
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------     --------------  -----         
 0   date_time  17474 non-null  datetime64[ns]
 1   count      17474 non-null  int64         
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(1)
memory usage: 273.2 KB
```

`xlabels` are unreadable when plotting the dataframe as is (note that it would also be the case **without** duplicated values in `date_time` column):

```py
df.plot(x="date_time", kind="bar", stacked=True)
```

Output:

[image]

One way to fix that is to manually set `xticks`, for instance, to the index of each month end day using pandas [asfreq](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html), and then set `xlabels` accordingly by chain calling [set_xticklabels](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html) with the corresponding datetime values; at each step, duplicated values are taken into account so that, even if all values are plotted in the end, ticks and labels remain unique:

```py
# Index of end of months dates in df
df = df.sort_values(by="date_time").reset_index(drop=True)
end_of_months = (
    df[
        df["date_time"].isin(
            df.drop_duplicates(subset=["date_time"])
            .set_index(["date_time"])
            .asfreq("M")
            .reset_index()["date_time"]
        )
    ]
    .drop_duplicates(subset=["date_time"])
    .index.tolist()
)

df.plot(x="date_time", kind="bar", stacked=True, xticks=end_of_months).set_xticklabels(
    df.loc[end_of_months, "date_time"].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d").unique(),
    rotation=45,
    ha="right",
)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Finally had some time to look at this. Your solution doesn't work for me. I did not clarify it, but the column "date_time" is not unique. That column is not the index either. This complicates the matter a lot, since we cannot leverage the "index" for lookups based on another interval, such as "end-of-month" (Or, in my case, two-hourly).

Comment: Indeed, with duplicates in "date_time" column, it does not work. Do you care what ticks and labels are shown on the plot? Or, is it ok if the column is binned arbitrarily?

Comment: I would prefer to have every nth hour shown. Some consistency, on the x-axis.

Comment: Hi, I've updated my answer to deal with an example where there are duplicated values in  "date_time" column. Cheers.