# disable x axis labels or give few labels to bar plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

How disable the xaxis label or give few labels to in following bar plot

```
df.reset_index().plot(x ='created_time', y='shares_count', kind = 'bar')
```

because of it has large number of 'created_time' its coming like this in x axis

[image]

Comment: Some possible solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608788/changing-the-tick-frequency-on-x-or-y-axis-in-matplotlib)

Comment: And here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73182266/11246056